# selecting the dropdowns having id selector starting with some string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five drop downs having the id element named as box_g1, box_g2, box_g3, box_g4 and box_g5. I want to enable all the disabled values in all the combo boxes with id selector starting with box_g.

**HTML :**

```
<select name="n1" id="box_g1">
    <option value="Default">Default</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>

<select name="n2" id="box_g2" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>

<select name="n3" id="box_g3" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<select name="n4" id="box_g4" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>

</select>
<select name="n5" id="box_g5" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>

</select>
```

**JQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(e){

        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var value = this.value;

        $("select option").each(function(){

            var idParent = $(this).parent().attr("id");

            if(id != idParent){
                if(this.value == value){
                    this.disabled = true;
                }

                else if($("#box_g1 option:selected").val()!="Default"){
                    $("#box_g2").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#box_g3").prop("disabled", false);
             $("#box_g4").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#box_g5").prop("disabled", false);
                }else{
                    /*$("#box_g1").each(function(){
                        $("#box_g1 option").removeAttr("disabled",false);
                    });                     
                    $("#box_g2").prop("disabled",true).val('Disabled');
                    $("#box_g3").prop("disabled",true).val('Disabled');
                    $("#box_g4").prop("disabled",true).val('Disabled');
                    $("#box_g5").prop("disabled",true).val('Disabled');*/

                    defaultValues();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

function defaultValues() {

        if ($("#box_g1").val() == "Default") {
            $("select[id^='box_g']").removeAttr("disabled",false); // added this line to enable all the values in all boxes but they are still disabled.
            $("#box_g2").attr("disabled", true).val('Disabled');

            $("#box_g3").attr("disabled", true).val('Disabled');

            $("#box_g4").attr("disabled", true).val('Disabled');

            $("#box_g5").attr("disabled", true).val('Disabled');

        } else {
            $("#box_g2").attr("disabled", false);
            $("#box_g3").attr("disabled", false);
            $("#box_g4").attr("disabled", false);
            $("#box_g5").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help out on this. Check the function defaultValues(). I have mentioned the comment.

Comment: What problem you are getting here?

Comment: the values are not disabled .. please see the comment in defaultValues() function. All the values for all comboboxes are still disabled.

Comment: sorry. i have updated the comment. it was wrongly written ...

Comment: Have you disabled the selects, or the options?

Comment: i have enable all the options for all dropdowns but not for disabled values. Please check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/c97Luve7/1/

Comment: And what's the problem with that demo, exactly? What behaviour do you *not* want? What precise behaviour *do* you want? In response to what event?

Comment: I don't really get the point, why you want the options to be enabled, when you disable all the selects

Comment: For more understanding : All of you please check this url i have dropped question on crazyengineers too..
http://www.crazyengineers.com/threads/how-to-do-this-using-jquery-for-the-dropdown-functionality-for-multiple-dropdowns.77246/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable all the options with:

```
$('select[id^="box_g"] option').prop("disabled",false);
```

but the selects will still be disabled due to the lines following in your code

Comment: @ Shoaib Chikate Yes, it does work, if you comment out the lines, which disable the **selects** you can see that all the options are enabled. But as i said in the answer, he is disabling all the selects (not the options) after the line where he wants to enable the options, which makes enabling the options pretty pointless

Comment: Agree, I m still unable to understand OP :(

Comment: yes it is working. Thanks a lot. But i have one more issue. can i ask the same.. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want enable all select boxes whos od start whith 'box_g' you can use this

```
 $("select[id^='box_g']").find("option").prop("disabled",false);
```

Comment: no its not working Please check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rajan222000/c97Luve7/1/

Comment: Define 'not working,' guessing, as a rule, is a terrible way to answer, or improve an answer to, a question.

Comment: I have to enable all the options in box_g1,box_g2 and so on. i.e. if i have values A,B,C,D and E disabled, then all values in all boxes should be enabled after.

Comment: Sorry for earlier post.I have edited my ans.Now this will eanble all options in selects which starts from 'box_g'.Put this code where you want to do the same.